# MS Access Database

Tags: database, ms-access

Running a simple search query.

I have a table named books which has fields like

```
ISBN
Title
Name
```

What i want to do is to make a search query which asks the user for the title and then prints it out. The problem is that i want to make it partially searchable too. If the title name is "Kings book". If i search for kings this should show up too and that i dont have to search for the exact name.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Access available to me, but you might try putting this in your criteria field (or the WHERE clause of the code in SQL view).

This is a "*starts with*" query:
`LIKE & [Parameter] & "*"`

This is a "*contains*" query:
`LIKE "*" & [Parameter] & "*"`

See this link http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut01.htm